# Azure DevOps .Net sdk for creating Pipeline Programmatically

Tags: azure-devops, sdk

I'm trying to create new build pipeline through programmatically. Azure DevOps .net sdk doesn't seem to have pipeline specific methods. Can someone confirm

Documentation doesn't confirm any example for pipeline creation using .net sdk

Comment: Hi Akshay, what is the latest status of this issue? Has my post helped?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a console app with the code below. And edit your body with the [rest api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)

```
using RestSharp;

using System;



namespace ConsoleApp18

{

    class Program

    {

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines?api-version=7.0";

            string pat = "{PAT}";

            var client = new RestClient(url);

            var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.Post);

request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+pat);

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            var body = @"{

                        " + "\n" +

@"""runParameters"":""""

                        " + "\n" +

                       @"}";

request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var response = client.Execute(request);

Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself but I see that the Azure DevOps SDK I'm using has a method for that.

First, install Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client (i'm using version 16.205.1) and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient.

Look into how to create a VssConnection (you can use a PAT from your profile to connect using the SDK), example:

```
var connection = new VssConnection(azureDevopsOrgUri, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, testAccessToken));
```

Then use that connection to get the BuildHttpClient (it is IDisposable so better surround it with a `using` statement but for simplicity :

```
var buildClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
```

Then you can use `CreateDefinitionAsync`:

```
await buildClient.CreateDefinitionAsync(); // pass a BuildDefinition instance as a parameter
```